# Event handler for when a user has added an image

Tags: jquery, file, event-handling, input

I have a form that lets users upload a image of them self. I need an jQuery event handler for when the input in uploaded.

```
<script>
  $('#imageFile').someeventhander(function(){do some work son!});
</script>

<input id="imageFile" type="file">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload a file you need the server to accept it and send a response back to the browser. jQuery can then use the response to trigger an event or call a function. So the answer depends on how your server is handling the upload.

swfUpload is a popular solution that uses a small Flash movie the handling the uploading. There is a jQuery plugin for it that triggers numerous events that allow you to monitor start/progress/error/completion of the upload.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complex problem, as file inputs do not upload until you submit a form. See this related question:

[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221)

Comment: Well i think I just found the answer. I didn't really want that much specificity for this. So .change I think will do the job.

Comment: Although that link is very helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#imageFile').change I believe is what I needed.
```